# How to authenticate sandbox to VS Code with Multi-factor required

Tags: single-sign-on, vs-code

I am trying to authenticate my VS Code to one of my sandbox and when I am entering my credential into the salesforce UI it is literally doing nothing and when I am checking login history for my user, it is saying "Multi-factor required". Am I missing any setting here?

Comment: have you set up MFA in that org?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves : Yes, MFA is already setup in that org and when I do normal login it asks for extra security check (sending code to OKTA verify)